# Potentil developer. ;)

Tags: development

I am a 16 year old boy from Austria which want`s to start developing apps for ubuntu (mobile). Are there some links for a newbie like me? ^^

Sorry if I am new. Just wanna try to develop and take a deeper look into Ubuntu.

Cheers Elias

Comment: This is too broad a topic for a question on here. However, there is plenty of documentation on http://developer.ubuntu.com/ about this, and you can join #ubuntu-app-devel on Freenode IRC to discuss the process.